# Extract inherited class argument from constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, command, command-pattern

first of all sorry if I'll be using a messy terminology, I'm still learning a lot about the Command pattern and C#.

I'm trying to implement the command pattern in Unity3D using C#, specifically [this implementation](https://github.com/Habrador/Unity-Programming-Patterns/tree/master/Assets/Patterns/1.%20Command) readapted to my case.

Given the [Command.cs](https://github.com/Habrador/Unity-Programming-Patterns/blob/master/Assets/Patterns/1.%20Command/Command.cs) and the [GameController.cs](https://github.com/Habrador/Unity-Programming-Patterns/blob/master/Assets/Patterns/1.%20Command/Rebind%20keys/Scripts/GameController.cs) scripts, I've created a `DoThing` class, inheriting from the `Command` class, implemented with the following code:

```
public class DoThing : Command
{
    public string name;
    public int healthPoints;

    public DoThing(string name, int healthPoints)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.healthPoints = healthPoints;
    }
}
```

Now, since I passed some arguments to the Commands through a constructor (`name`, `healthPoints`), I'd want to extract those from another script.

I tried (successfully) to pass the arguments to a command in the following line and to save the command in a stack:

```
var doCommand = new DoThing("asdf", 123);
Stack<Command> listOfCommands = new Stack<Command>();
listOfCommands.Push(doCommand);
```

And I tried (successfully) retrieving those arguments *in the watch window, during code execution*:

```
listOfCommands.Peek().name //returns "asdf"
```

But then this doesn't work in the script, meaning that the arguments can't be seen:

```
Debug.Log(listOfCommands.Peek().name) //throws error
```

is there a way to extract the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `listOfCommands` is a `Stack` of `Command`, `listOfCommands.Peek()` returns a `Command` which does not have the `name` variable. You have to check the type of the variable returned by the function and cast it before accessing the variable.

```cs
Command command = listOfCommands.Peek();
if(command is DoThing)
{
    Debug.Log(((DoThing) command).name);
}
```

or more compact

```cs
if(listOfCommands.Peek() is DoThing doThing)
{
    Debug.Log(doThing.name);
}
```

or

```cs
DoThing doThing = listOfCommands.Peek() as DoThing;
if(doThing != null)
{
    Debug.Log(doThing.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) wiki:

> A command object knows about receiver and invokes a method of the receiver. Values for parameters of the receiver method are stored in the
> command. The receiver object to execute these methods is also stored
> in the command object by aggregation. The receiver then does the work
> when the execute() method in command is called. **An invoker object
> knows how to execute a command, and optionally does bookkeeping about
> the command execution. The invoker does not know anything about a
> concrete command, it knows only about the command interface.**

So if what the `DoThing` command does is log a message to the console, it should look like this:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public abstract void Execute();        
}

public class DoThing : Command
{
    public string name;
    public int healthPoints;

    public DoThing(string name, int healthPoints)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.healthPoints = healthPoints;
    }
    public override void Execute(){
        Debug.Log(name);
        // whatever else the command does
    }
}
```

And you would call execute on the command.